# AngularJS ng-repeat - Data list inside a another list items

Tags: angularjs, datalist

I want to bind a data list. But this data list is inside a another list. In following code `ng-repeat="Menu in Menus"` is working properly. but `ng-repeat="TopCat in Menu.TopCategories"` is not working and it is inside the list.

```
<li ng-repeat="Menu in Menus">
                    <a href="#" class="mainCategoryLink"><img src="~/Images/{{Menu.MenuDetails.ImageUrl}}" />{{Menu.MenuDetails.Category}}</a>
                    <div class="dropdownSection">
                        <div class="dropdownContainer clearfix">
                            <div class="topCategories">
                                <h2 class="fontsize13 blue3">Top Categories</h2>
                                <ul ng-repeat="TopCat in Menu.TopCategories">
                                    <li>Category{{TopCat.MenuDetails.TopCategories.Category}}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

This is my class and i want to get data from topCategories to `ng-repeat="TopCat in Menu.TopCategories"`

```
        IList<TopCategory> topCategories = new List<TopCategory>();
        topCategories.Add(new TopCategory { Id = 1, ImageUrl = "iconMonitor.png", Category = "Cameras" });
        topCategories.Add(new TopCategory { Id = 1, ImageUrl = "iconAppliance.png", Category = "Laptops" });
        topCategories.Add(new TopCategory { Id = 1, ImageUrl = "iconCar.png", Category = "Monitors" });

        IList<LeftMenuResponse> leftMenu = new List<LeftMenuResponse>();
        leftMenu.Add(new LeftMenuResponse { Id = 1, ImageUrl = "iconMonitor.png", Category = "Electronics", TopCategories = topCategories, OtherCategories = otherCategories });
        leftMenu.Add(new LeftMenuResponse { Id = 1, ImageUrl = "iconAppliance.png", Category = "Appliances", TopCategories = topCategories, OtherCategories = otherCategories });
        leftMenu.Add(new LeftMenuResponse { Id = 1, ImageUrl = "iconCar.png", Category = "Auto Parts", TopCategories = topCategories, OtherCategories = otherCategories });

        return leftMenu;
```

Comment: try to use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude)

Comment: Your HTML part seems correct, please post other stuff like JS and `Menus` model. BTW, plunker/fiddle will be good as well

Comment: Thanks Maxim... This is my Class